# How to solve this switch-case problem, when my clause is not working for one case

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Here in the below switch-case condition it is throwing error
`Cannot read property 'entity' of undefined`  because for every other case except `"paytm"` the entity is present in the `"payload"` but for paytm its `"payload_data"` --> `body.data.payload_data.entity.channel`
How to solve this issue.

```
switch(body.data.payload.entity.channel){
            case "paytm"  : 
                await paytm(body);
                break;
            case "phonePe" : 
                await phonePe(body);
                break;    
            case "googlePay":
            default:
                await googlePay(body);
        }
```

I tried adding multiple things but it didnt worked for me.

Comment: Why not just fix the data?

Comment: `const channel = body.data.payload?.entity?.channel ?? body.data.payload_data?.entity?.channel`. And then `swtich(channel)`

Comment: Or if you are okay with putting `payload_data` to `payload` property: `body.data.payload ??= body.data.payload_data?`

Answer (score 0):

Use `optional chain operator`

```
  const targetChannel =
    body?.data?.payload?.entity?.channel ||
    body.data.payload_data.entity.channel;
  switch (targetChannel) {
    case "paytm":
      await paytm(body);
      break;
    case "phonePe":
      await phonePe(body);
      break;
    case "googlePay":
    default:
      await googlePay(body);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) to ensure that if the `payload` property is not present, then the `payload_data` property is used instead:

> You can repeatedly press the "Run code snippet" button below to see randomized results in the console.

```html
<script type="module">

function simulateRandomBody () {
  const channel = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "phonePe" : "googlePay";
  return Math.random() < 0.5
    ? { data: { payload: { entity: { channel } } } }
    : { data: { payload_data: { entity: { channel: "paytm" } } } };
}

const paytm = console.log.bind(console);
const phonePe = console.log.bind(console);
const googlePay = console.log.bind(console);

const body = simulateRandomBody();

switch ((body.data.payload ?? body.data.payload_data).entity.channel) {
  case "paytm":
    await paytm(body);
    break;
  case "phonePe":
    await phonePe(body);
    break;
  case "googlePay":
  default:
    await googlePay(body);
}


</script>
```